# i want the full sample that can split an image into parts using flutter in fact i can not find a hole sample for spliting image into pars in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-layout

When I click the button, the function split the image into 3*3 parts

```
Image img =Image(image: AssetImage('assets/crossflutter.png'));

int h=3;
int v=3;
```

when I call the function that split the image into parts

```
parts= splitImage( inputImage:img,horizontalPieceCount:h,verticalPieceCount:v);
```

[image]

the problem is

[image]

How to split an image into equal-sized parts? Just taking an image from asset and splitting it into equal parts in a grid-like manner, so that each image part can be used as a separate image.

```
List<Image> splitImage({required Image inputImage, required int horizontalPieceCount, required int verticalPieceCount}) {
```

How to split an image into equal-sized parts? Just taking an image from asset and splitting it into equal parts in a grid-like manner, so that each image part can be used as a separate image.

Comment: Can you please update the formatting of the question? Currently it is quite unreadable.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet instead of code-image?